# 422 unprocessable entity when requesting an image or excel file

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, postman

I'm doing an api with an upload file using multipart/form-data, Unfortunately when I'm trying to use an xlsx file or other certain files, it always returns an 422 unprocessable entity.

Is there some sort of configuration to enable the uploading of other files?

Code below :

```
[Route("api/test")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public TestController()
    {
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("import")]
    public ActionResult ImportFile([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream strm = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                return Ok($"File uploaded had {file?.Length ?? -1} bytes");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core aren't the same thing. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: removed the asp reference, i'm using core

Comment: What are your approximate needs? Do you use asp.net core to upload the xlsx file and then parse it to return its bytes?

Comment: file is only 30kb, and the request limit is 20mb. I want to read it using openxml. Although it seems like it's not going trough the method